# Update iOS Cordova WebView when app is in brackground

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I'm building an app for iOS and Android. The app has a JavaScript counter, which updates the time every seconds. When I press the home button in Android and the I come back, the counter is right, it updates when the app is on background, but the iOS doesn't.

Is there a way to make the iOS update the WebView on background?

Sample JS code to update the counter:

```
setInterval(){
   $('#div').html(counter);
   counter -= 1;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: JS pause in background mode. Use pause + resume event to make counter right.

Comment: You mean that JS stops updating the element, but the setInterval keeps running?

Comment: Yes, when your app in background, it will pause anything(connection, js code,..) as soon as possible for performance device. Only several code from native still running: service(Android), background feed(IOS),..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid tt's **not** really possible to this in *background* mode on **iOS**.

As @Hanh-le mentioned iOS will stop (pause) your app in about 10 seconds from the moment you send it to the background.
Only some native functionality (service) can keep it running (like music playing, bluetooth running in the background, etc).
This services can actually call javascript otherwise `Javascript` will be stopped.

**EDIT** (added your function of setinterval) if you set up your interval like this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem(
    'counterInterval', 
    setInterval({
        $('#div').html(counter);
        counter -= 1;
    }, 1000);
);
```

You could save the timestamp on the `onPause()` event and also clear your interval

```
function onPause() {
    clearInterval(window.localStorage.getItem('counterInterval');
    window.localStorage.setItem('pauseTime', new Date());
}
```

and then check for the elapsed time on `onResume()` event and then update your counter:

```
function onResume() {
    var resumeTime = new Date(),
        pauseTime = window.localStorage.getItem('pauseTime'),
        elapsedTime = (resumeTime.getTime() - pauseTime.getTime()) / 1000;
        //you can round elapsedTime if you'd like
        elapsedTime = Math.round(elapsedTime);

    //correct the counter
    $('#div').html(counter);
    counter -= elapsedTime;    

    //set interval again until the next `Pause` event
    window.localStorage.setItem(
        'counterInterval', 
        setInterval({
            $('#div').html(counter);
            counter -= 1;
        }, 1000);
    );
}
```

This would save resources on background mode anyway...

Comment: Your solution worked (with a few adjustments). Thanks!